# Codename One - if clause to target the iOS build server

Tags: codenameone

I know that the iOS apps are runned by the iOS build servers to generate screenshots. In some cases this behavior can be a problem.

I know that I can disable the iOS screenschots generation using the build hint `ios.fastBuild=true`, however my question is if possible to target the iOS build server with an if clause like this:

```
if (CN1BuildServer) {
   ...
}
else {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to officially support that but if you can clarify the use case it will help.

Personally to generate a screenshot I use code like this:

```
if(Preferences.get("firstTime", true)) {
   Preferences.set("firstTime", false);
   // show a splash screen
}
```

You can further limit this to iOS platform only although I don't normally do that. It will happen on the device but only on first launch.

Comment: Thank you. I clarify my use case: if I use the MediaPlayer in the first Form, the screenshot generation fails because it's a native component. If I disable the screenshot generation, it fails again but with a different error. In the code, I don't show the MediaPlayer if "Display.getInstance().isSimulator()=true" (because the Simulator gets stuck loading the video with skins different from iPhone3gs, and it also generates an exception, instead the video is fine on real devices). It could be nice to add the condition "Display.getInstance().isCN1BuildServer()=true" to don't show the MediaPlayer.

Comment: Of course I can solve as you suggested with a splash screen... or enclosing all the code of the MediaPlayer in a try...catch.

Comment: Yes, media on the first form is problematic. I think a better approach would be `MediaManager.isSupported()` which will allow you to show an image representing the media  instead.